# Regex; how to match all of the "[0]" occurances in a string?

Tags: regex, match

I cannot figure out how to do this.  I;ve tried some suggestions found here, such as;

[([0]]+)

but they only return the first occurance of "[0]", I want it to match other occurances in a string.

Thanks

Comment: What language are you using? Languages like PHP have preg_match and preg_match_**all**

Comment: Remember this will most likely return an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex:

```
(\[0\])
```

Explanation:

```
(   - Start of capture
 \[ - [ is a regex meta-character, used for char class. 
      To match a literal [ escape it.
 0  - A literal 0
 \] - A literal ]
)   - End of capture
```

[**See it**](http://www.rubular.com/r/JuKFoXZeye)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify a language; the JavaScript regex would be:

```
/\[0\]/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Most regex dialects require you to specify that you want more than one match.

The regex `+` which you've used in your code will only help you pick up matches which are immediately next to each other. If you want more than one match that are in separate places in the string, you'll need a different technique.

You haven't specified the language you're using, so it's hard to be specific, but in general you would use the `g` modifier to specify multiple matches.

eg in Javascript:  `mystring.match(/\[0\]/g)`

An exception to that is PHP, where you would use `preg_match_all()` instead of `preg_match()`.

Other languages will differ -- please tell us what you're working in.